# Grab rows in order using WHERE IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT,
    name TEXT
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES
    (1, "John"),
    (2, "Susan"),
    (3, "Timothy"),
    (4, "Robert"),
    (5, "Jim"),
    (6, "Patricia");

$var = $db->prepare("
    SELECT name
        FROM users
        WHERE id IN (3, 2, 4, 6)
");
$var->execute();
```

This returns a result in the order of which an `id` appears in the table, so "2, 3, 4, 6". Is there a way to order this in the order specified in the `WHERE ... IN` clause?

Expected result would be:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  3 |
|  2 |
|  4 |
|  6 |
+----+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an `order by` to get things in order.  One way is to use `field()`:

```
SELECT name
FROM users
WHERE id IN (3, 2, 4, 6)
ORDER BY field(id, 3, 2, 4, 6);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name
FROM users
WHERE id IN (3, 2, 4, 6)
order by find_in_set(id, '3,2,4,6')
```